# My background image displays in google chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

Can someone help me understand why Chrome but not Firefox is able to display the background image of the tree on the right side and how to fix: [www.eye45.com](http://www.eye45.com)

When the web browser is contracted, both

```
<div class="col-sm-6 left-side">
<div class="col-sm-6 right-side">
```

are supposed to maintain the same height until 
@media (max-width: 780px) {} and then the tree image is supposed to flip under the purple paragraphs and reduce to a height of 200px.

It works perfect in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: try to set height in px / vh, it ll work

Comment: show me ur code

Comment: nice domain name "eye45" ahhaahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding style with display as table will fix this for firefox.

```
.right-side {
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="display:table"`

```
<div class="col-sm-6 right-side" style="display: table;">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a height problem in chrome browser. use this

```
.right-side {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this a height problem in Firefox, because the `div` in question doesn't have any content. You might as well name this a height problem in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this and found that it won't be responsive and maintain equal height with the left-side.

Answer (score 1):

Try using equal height columns bootstrap css in your code.

Reference : http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

```css
.left-side {
  background: #bbb4e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2%;
}
.right-side {
  background: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/igd-wp-uploads/2014/05/Perfei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Igni%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Digital.jpg") no-repeat 50% center / cover ;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-sm-6 left-side">
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 right-side">

  </div>

</div>
```

Here is demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrJBzz

Comment: This displays the image on the right side, but doesn't let the image slip below, when the width decreases.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't have time tonight to experiment with your proposal. Tomorrow I will look into it further.

Comment: It's an interesting approach nevertheless.